# Using non-shared methods for a union-typed variable in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm converting a javascript library to typescript. I'm running into an issue in which a single variable can be either a boolean or an array.

This can't change because it's fed by external JSON data - and because the user expects the data structure to remain unchanged, I can't split it into two variables.

My problem is that even though I can define a union type, the methods I later access once this is an array do *not* exist on the boolean.

So typescript complains with `error TS2339: Property 'push' does not exist on type 'boolean | string[]'.`

```
var children: boolean | Array<string>;

children = [];
children.push('test');
```

This is very simple code example that produces the result I'm getting. How can I work around this?

Comment: Would the [any](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any) type work or are you trying to avoid that?

Comment: That  works, I'd prefer not to be so generic but I'm fairly sure I've got no choice.

Answer (score 0):

> This is very simple code example that produces the result I'm getting. How can I work around this

TypeScript understands JavaScript :)

The following code runs *fine* in TypeScript latest:

```
var children: boolean | Array<string>;

children = [];
children.push('test');
```

Because it has more agressive code flow analysis ;)

## More

TypeScript version : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/getting-started.html

## Legacy

You can use a type guard in current stable version of TypeScript if you want (I'd just move to latest). More on type guards : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/typeGuard.html

Comment: So you're advising that I install the `typescript@next` version instead of 1.8.10 and that will properly handle this use case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types):

```
if (children instanceof Array) {
    children.push('test');
}
```

or

```
if (typeof children === "boolean") {
    // children is boolean
}
```

Sometimes you need to do something a bit more complex than a one liner `console.log` and then it's convenient to have different functions who deal with the different possible types:

```
var children: boolean | Array<string>;
if (children instanceof Array) {
    useChildrenArray(children);
} else {
    useChildrenBoolean(children);
}

function useChildrenBoolean(children: boolean) { ... }
function useChildrenArray(children: Array<string>) { ... }
```